# TableCell views in UITableView not appearing in simulator iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been reading the docs like mad trying to solve my problem, but I don't believe my problem is too difficult, I'm probably going about it wrong. Here's my `UIViewController`:

[image]

And here's what it looks like in the simulator:

[image: imgur image]

I just need my populated cells to actually appear in the simulator. I have set the data and delegate source using this in .h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *grTableView;
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDataSource> dataSource;
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
```

This in `viewDidLoad` of .m:

```
grTableView.dataSource = self;
grTableView.delegate = self;
```

And I would like to set the spacing with this method(I'm aware that I can do with constraints, but am not sure **how**):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
        return 6;
    return 1.0;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5.0;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
```

I'm also currently trying to implement the cells using these methods(When I delete these methods, the cell borders appear as gray lines in the simulator, but the cells **are not** populated):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

How can I simply make the objects inside my cells(in storyboard) appear in simulator **and** work? 
If you need to see the *document outline*, *.m*, or *.h*, or *other simulator runs* just request it and I will post.

**P.S.**  The UIButton at the bottom is constrained using bottomLayoutGuide.

**EDIT:** Here is the implementation for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return grImageNameCell;
    return grBioCell;
}
```

and here's the .h code for those IBOutlets:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *grImageNameCell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *grBioCell;
```

Comment: How is your - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath implemented? You show a declaration and talk about what happens when you remove it but how are you implementing it?

Comment: And do you have Cell Reuse identifiers setup for each prototyped cell?

Comment: I have no cell reuse Identifiers but I do only want two Sections.. or two cells I guess. One sec and I'll have the implementation posted in an edit

Comment: Sorry I do want two sections.. I need it to look like this.. (I'm going to post a picture of a `UITableViewController` that I'm trying to replicate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for simple cell loading:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return self.objectsArray.count;//where this is your array that you'll use to populate cells
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"identifier here";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CellIdentifiers is kind of required for prototyped cells. This is how the code knows which cell(s) to use from the Interface Builder.

So, you need to do a few things here:

First, set unique Cell Identifiers to each prototyped cell in the Interface Builder

Setup your cellForRowAtIndexPath method something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath

{
   NSString* CellID1 = @"CellID1";
   NSString* CellID2 = @"CellID2";

   UITableViewCell* cell;

   if (indexPath.section == 0)
   {
      cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellID1];
   }
   else
   {
      cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellID2];
   }

   return cell;
}
```

Note: CellID1 and CellID2 are the identifiers.

Comment: Ok. I'm about to try this

Comment: Yeah that's not working. I'm getting a compilation error at runtime, I'm not sure if that's b/c those `NSString`'s need to be `UITableViewCell`'s or what.. no error message given and I've been trying to fix it

Comment: The strings are just cell identifiers. The cell is already an UITableViewCell. What is the compilation error/warning?

Comment: No error message. It's just listed under `main.storyboard` and says "Interface Builder Storyboard: compilation error. I set the Identity in "attributes inspector" and the restoration ID in the "Identity inspector" to the CellID1 and CellID2 respectively.

Comment: Sorry that's a confusion comment at the beginning, there **IS** an error message, but it only identifies the error to be in the storybaord

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your Interface Builder for the table cell(s)? Restoration ID isn't necessary. Only Identifier under TableViewCell is.

Comment: The screenshot is the first pic on this page.. it still looks exactly the same right now. I do actually have the cells currently hooked up to two UITableViewCell properties.

Comment: Sorry I mean of the interface builder itself. The options where you type in the cell identifier. Not the storyboard part. Example: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s249/sh/7c9923fc-e5c2-4877-9af9-7e78731c48e3/68eb03daa496fefa20484b65be1f83c2

Comment: I posted it to the bottom of the question

Comment: Ok. Have you tried removing whatever you put in Restoration ID under the other tab?

Comment: Yes I have removed both of the Restoration ID's.

Comment: Hmm not sure then why the storyboard would be complaining about something as simple as cell identifiers. I've never used the restoration IDs myself.

Comment: Actually it's now saying "Method definition for `numberOfRowsInSection:` not found." Up at the @implementation for the .m file

Comment: Ahh well add that delegate method in then. As well as numberOfSectionsInTable

Comment: Yeah I actually have both of those added, and in both of them I have just `return 2`. Within each method that is